# Crontab: Setting Timezone

Tags: python, timezone, cron

I have a django-based website installed on a shared web server. I am planning to have few cron jobs to automate creation of reports, sending emails etc. The problem is that the Timezone of the shared server is "America/New_York" (since it's a shared server I don't have the permission to change it) while I have to run the crons according to "Asia/Kolkata" timezone. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

**Updated after Chris's answer**

I set my local system TZ to 'America/New_York'

```
$ crontab -e

TZ=Asia/Kolkata

#(Accoring to some timezone dt: 21 July 11, time: 20:20)

20 20 * * * python test.py > test_log.txt
```

------ test.py ------

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
print dt.now()
```

------ test_log.txt ----

```
2011-07-22 08:42:02.592777
```

which is the time according to tz='Asia/Kolkata'. My question is: can we execute the script test.py according to Asia/Kolkata timezone?

Comment: I was going to suggest just offsetting the time in the crontab, but then I realized that probably wouldn't actually work when the use of daylight saving time is factored in.

Comment: So to tackle that the only way is to dynamically create crontab entries.

Comment: Instead of datetime.now(), consider datetime.utcnow() and offset accordingly. Read this article for more: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/7/15/eppur-si-muove/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be to have the cron run at 20 minutes past every hour, then have the script check whether it is the right Asia time and only continue if it is.

Comment: could not find anything better. this seems like the best option for me right now. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in your crontab:

```
TZ=Asia/Kolkata
```

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks, but if I am not wrong this will set the environment variable as the specified time zone (in this case Asia/Kolkata). So any scripts/commands will use this timezone. But the script itself will be executed according to the timezone of the server, right?